# Enhancement type nmos threshold voltage

Tags: nmos

in an enhancement type nmos when a channel is created then a depletion layer should be created under the n-channel which means electrons get a potential barrier to overcome.now is this potential barrier is included in threshold voltage??

Comment: On the other side of the depletion region is the gate, not another depletion region. And no current should be flowing to or from the gate.

Comment: between body and channel a depletion layer should be created.isn't it?

Comment: The channel *is* the depletion layer in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Your Channel is Itself in depletion region***

To understand whats happening imagine a freshly created MOSFET a just newly put together wafer(`though they are diffused with impurity but just for example lets imageine`),so as you are using NMOS your substrate is P type,and Source and Drain is N type.
At first instant both the regions of the Source and Drain they have both carriers(e in S and D and holes in P substrate)  which will diffuse across the barrier creating a depletion region i.e there are no charge ,only immobile ions there,the diffusion will stop when  a voltage cause by the immobile ions exceed the gradient voltage of carriers.

This voltage now stops the diffusion of the carriers,and is called the **Threshold Voltage**.(Vth)

Now as your NMOS is enhancement type you will have no pre-made channel,all you have is depletion region lying between the DRAIN and the SOURCE.A channel is one which has free carrier to casue flow of charge,you already have a depletion region all you need is charge.
Voltage through gate that will be act against the Threshold voltage,and hence will create a voltage difference along with action of attracting electrons form the substrate to act as carrier in depletion region.Now By applying a suitable Drain voltage you can have a current flow through the channel.